# How could I write CASE Clause in sql server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

How could i write CASE Clause in sql server 2005 ? it errors
Here is my code :

```
CASE @accesslevel 
        WHEN 'Order' THEN 
            INSERT INTO Permissions(UserAccountID,PrintOrder) 
            VALUES(@userid,1)

        WHEN 'Cashier' THEN 
            INSERT INTO Permissions(UserAccountID,PrintInvoice,SaveAndClear)
            VALUES(@userid,1,1) 

        WHEN 'Supervisor' THEN 
            INSERT INTO Permissions(UserAccountID,TableOperation,
                ExchangeRate,SaleReport,Section,Category,
                MenuItem,DeleteOrder,DeleteOneItem,MergeTable,
                SplitTable,PrintInvoice,PrintOrder,CalculateChange,
                SaveAndClea)
            VALUES(@userid,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1) 

        WHEN 'Manager' THEN 
            INSERT INTO Permissions(UserAccountID,TableOperation,
                ExchangeRate,SaleReport,Section,Category,
                MenuItem,DeleteOrder,DeleteOneItem,MergeTable,
                SplitTable,PrintInvoice,PrintOrder,CalculateChange,
                SaveAndClear,DailyIncome)
            VALUES(@userid,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1) 

        ELSE 
            INSERT INTO Permissions(UserAccountID,TableOperation,
                ExchangeRate,TablePicture,SaleReport,DailyIncome,
                Section,Category,MenuItem, UserAccount,UserPermission,
                StaffManagement,DeleteOrder,DeleteOneItem,MergeTable,
                SplitTable,PrintInvoice,PrintOrder,CalculateChange,
                SaveAndClear)
            VALUES(@userid,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
    END CASE
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [using Switch like logic in T-SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207799/using-switch-like-logic-in-t-sql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can use `CASE` statement to execute some actions (inserts, updates...), it's used to calculate expressions. You can use `IF..ELSE` statement:

```
IF @accesslevel = 'Order'
    INSERT INTO Permissions(UserAccountID,PrintOrder) 
    VALUES(@userid,1)

ELSE IF @accesslevel = 'Cashier'
      INSERT INTO Permissions(UserAccountID,PrintInvoice,SaveAndClear)
      VALUES(@userid,1,1)

     ELSE IF @accesslevel = 'Supervisor'
           INSERT INTO Permissions(UserAccountID,TableOperation,
             ExchangeRate,SaleReport,Section,Category,
             MenuItem,DeleteOrder,DeleteOneItem,MergeTable,
             SplitTable,PrintInvoice,PrintOrder,CalculateChange,
             SaveAndClea)
           VALUES(@userid,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1) 

          ELSE IF @accesslevel = 'Manager'
                INSERT INTO Permissions(UserAccountID,TableOperation,
                    ExchangeRate,SaleReport,Section,Category,
                    MenuItem,DeleteOrder,DeleteOneItem,MergeTable,
                    SplitTable,PrintInvoice,PrintOrder,CalculateChange,
                    SaveAndClear,DailyIncome)
                VALUES(@userid,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1) 

               ELSE
                INSERT INTO Permissions(UserAccountID,TableOperation,
                    ExchangeRate,TablePicture,SaleReport,DailyIncome,
                    Section,Category,MenuItem, UserAccount,UserPermission,
                    StaffManagement,DeleteOrder,DeleteOneItem,MergeTable,
                    SplitTable,PrintInvoice,PrintOrder,CalculateChange,
                    SaveAndClear)
                VALUES(@userid,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

CASE expressions are for use inside SQL Server Expressions, like:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 1 = 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END
```

What you are trying to do above (conditionally executing statements or blocks of statements) should be done with `IF` / `ELSE` (optionally using `BEGIN` and `END` to enclose multiple statements).

We often/usually say "Case Statement", but actually the correct term is "Case Expression", as they are used **within** expressions, within statements (msdn ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx).